# Excel Crash : not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel program with some code that has been running without problem for several months. Today it started crashing and I have no idea why. It may have nothing to do with the code but I pasted it below with the place where it seems to crash. When I walk through it step by step it runs fine. Thanks.

```
Sub Merge()

    Sheets("Working").Select
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[1],""mmm"")"

Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
Columns("A:A").Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("G1").Consolidate Sources:= _
    "'Working'!R1C1:R[" & lastRow & "]C2" _
    , Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False


Sheets("Landing").Select
Range("E10:F21").ClearContents

Range("E10").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Working!C[2]:C[3],2,FALSE)"
Range("F10").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-2]"
Range("E10:F10").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E10:F21"), Type:=xlFillDefault


        On Error Resume Next
        Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents ' Delete #N/A
        On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd start by removing all of the `.Select` / `Selection.` entries to tidy it up and make everything fully qualified.

Comment: Also, you state that Excel 'crashes'. Can you elaborate on how it crashes? Does it hang, error or 'quits unexpectedly'?

Comment: Hi, I edited the code above. I am not an expert at vba so if I didn't go through everything I could, please let me know. Excel quits, goes to the screen where it is "trying to find a fix" and then shuts down completely. Sometimes it gives me the option to debug (which I don't know how to do). When I click on that, it says "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in excel.exe [2524]"

Comment: Have you tried running the macro from another computer? What has changed on the computer since the last time the macro ran successfully? What version of Excel and what OS are you using? Also, the `Sheets().Select` statements should be replaced with `With Sheets()` blocks.

Comment: That's certainly better, though there is more you could do - that conversation is for another time - there's plenty of guides for using `WITH` etc.. I'd now start to insert a breakpoint (or a `STOP`) within the code, just to find exactly what command is causing the issue. My gut-feeling is that it's probably the `Sheets("Landing").Select` line, trying to run before the `.Consolidate` has finished but I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi! I did that. I added the stop at the `Sheets("Landing").Select`. Before I stepped into that, the I can see the consolidate finished on the `Working` Sheet. As i stepped into the code, it crashed right after highlighting the `vlookup` line. Any ideas? I am also curious why this has been running fine for months and now it is crashing.

Comment: Do you mean that it is crashing before the `VLOOKUP` (while attempting to `ClearContents`) or after/while trying to calculate it? If it is the `VLOOKUP` that crashes, does it need to search the whole of the columns? It might help to restrict the number of rows it is searching, i.e. `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],Working!R[1]C[2]:R[**Put in your number of rows**]C[3],2,FALSE)"`.

Comment: Hi again - sorry for not responding. I was off for a few days. It is definitely the `vlookup` - it crashes while trying to calculate it. Even even when I do it manually (outside of vba) it crashed a few times. I feel like I am going crazy, its not a complicate piece of code! I limited the cells it looks in and it still crashes. Any other ideas?